# Firestore - C# conditional update using ETag/If-Match?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm researching Google Cloud products and Firestore in particular. I see that using the REST API, Firestore populates the ETag header, or perhaps its own `X-Firebase-ETag`, the docs aren't clear.

I see it supports conditional updates, as it should, via the `if-match` header.

However I cannot see this critical functionality exposed via the .NET SDK. I can only see a `Precondition.LastUpdateTime` property which can be used via the `DocumentReference.UpdateAsync` method. `SetOptions` has nothing of use.

Am I out of luck? Must I write my own REST implementation if I want to use Firestore?

**Update**

I posted a feature request to the Firestore team. Jon Skeet, who appears to be fielding GitHub issues on the GCP libs for C#, says that the underlying gRPC does not support this, even though the REST API does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not currently supported. The feature is not available in the underlying gRPC API.

Here's a link to the API that affords conditional updates.

[DocumentReference.UpdateAsync](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference#Google_Cloud_Firestore_DocumentReference_UpdateAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_Google_Cloud_Firestore_FieldPath_System_Object__Google_Cloud_Firestore_Precondition_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)